# A science fiction film that had a transgender person who went crazy or something and either killed or attempted to kill the crew

Tags: story-identification, movie, space

I don't know the title but some of the crew identify a drug that is used by transgender people, and that person is suspected of murder or something.

Comment: Hi!  When and where did you see this?  I assume, from "crew" and the "space" tag, that this took place on a spaceship?  What did it look like?  How many crew were there, and were there any notable characters?  Who was the hero?

Comment: This question is very terse and could be improved by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Answer (score 6):

This initial question sounded vaguely familiar, and a quick look up suggests it could be [Murder on The Moon](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0097931/?ref_=nm_flmg_t_32_act), a TV movie made in 1989.

The IMDB summary indicates that a pair of space cops, one from the US and one from the Soviet Union, team up to solve the titular murder.

My recollection is that during the investigation they discover something - possibly a hormone blocker - that suggests that the murderer may be transgender, which is why I think it might be the title the original poster remembers.

It turns out that the murderer is

> a known fugitive, who has changed sex as a disguise,
>  and that the murder victim had uncovered their original
>  identity and is threating to reveal it.

Not certain how I recalled this, after close to 30 years, and I could be wrong.